# Can I make `find` return non-0 when no matching files are found?

Tags: find

Even when `/tmp` has no file called `something`, searching for it with `find` will return 0:

```
  $ find /tmp -name something 
  $ echo $?
  0
```

How can I get a non-zero exit status when `find` does not find anything?

Comment: If your goal is to pass the list of filenames to a command that behaves poorly when given no arguments, a handy trick is to just add `/dev/null` as an extra argument. It is guaranteed to be empty, so if your goal is to run `wc` this is particularly helpful. Not an answer for every use case.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
find /tmp -name something | grep .
```

The return status will be `0` when something is found, and non-zero otherwise.

EDIT: Changed from `egrep '.*'` to the much simpler `grep .`, since the result is the same.

Comment: The trailing `*` on the `egrep` regex is completely redundant.  Since you are not using `egrep` regular expression syntax, plain old `grep` might be a few microseconds faster.

Comment: i learned to use `find ... | read`

Comment: read returns the appropriate exit code, but note that it swallows the result if any

Comment: `grep -F ''` does not use regular expressions at all and results in the same output as `grep .`.

Comment: `find ... | read` is perfect for my use case, I wanted it to swallow the output.  Anyone who wants the exit code for branching probably doesn't need the output

Answer (score 37):

Exit 0 is easy with find, exit >0 is harder because that usually only happens
with an error. However we can make it happen:

```sh
if find -type f -exec false {} +
then
  echo 'nothing found'
else
  echo 'something found'
fi
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't work. The exit code of `find` doesn't seem to depend on the exit codes of any `-exec`s it ran.

Comment: Works like a clock. A big advantage of this solution is that it doesn't use pipes of subshells - nice for some scripting needs.

Comment: No, this will not work as the question was posed.  This solution will return 1 if the file is found.  It will return 0 if the file is found.  This is the opposite of what the OP asked.  However, this solution does work as a concept; it just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @shrewmouse I dont think you understand what the snippet is doing. Notice carefully the `if ... else` is inverted to handle your concern

Comment: This should be suffixed with `-quit` to immediately exit after a file is found.

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac I found that for dome reason this doesn't works anymore adding `-quit` option to find :s

Comment: To answer whether `find` depends on the exit code of `-exec`, the following blurb from the manual is useful: "If any invocation with the `+` form returns a non-zero value as exit  status, then find returns a non-zero exit status."

Comment: Lovely, just remember to add a `-print` in case you also want to list the files..

Comment: @Zombo Just put a `!` in front of the `find` command...

Comment: @TrippKinetics How to rewrite the snippet to make return `find` zero if something is found? Without `!` in front of the find command.

Comment: @pmor What exactly are you trying to do?  Just set a variable to `0` in your `something found` block and check for it later.

Answer (score 27):

Simplest solution that doesn't print, but exits 0 when results found

```
find /tmp -name something | grep -q "."
```

Comment: Double-quotes serve no purpose here.

Comment: While the double quotes serve no code function, they do make it clearer to a reader that the period character is a regex and not a directory.

Comment: And if you want the opposite (exit non-zero when the file is found), you can add a negation operator in front `! find /tmp -name badfile | grep -q .`

Comment: And if you want the script to halt on badfile, use `… || exit 1` or parens with `-e`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39581150/450917

Comment: `grep -q` will cause `find` to likely exit with `SIGPIPE`, which will be a problem if you use `-o pipefail`.

Answer (score 15):

Having just found this question whilst trying to find my way to solve a problem with Puppet (change permissions on folders under a directory but not on the directory itself), this seems to work:

```
test -n "$(find /tmp -name something)"
```

My specific use case is this:

```
test -n "$(find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -perm -711)"
```

Which will exit code 1 if the find command finds no files with the required permissions.

Comment: A few solutions (didn't try them all) here didn't work on a Mac; this did.

Comment: Just to note, this can also be written as `[[ -n "$(...)" ]]` if people find that more readable than using `test`.

Comment: I like this solution because it avoids the pipe and bumping of the PID counter. `[ "$(find ...)" ] && echo Found || echo Not found` with single bracket and no `-n` also works and is portable (POSIX).

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible. Find returns 0 if it exits successfully, even if it didn't find a file (which is a correct result *not* indicating an error when the file indeed doesn't exist).

To quote the find manpage

> EXIT STATUS
>
> find  exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully,
>   greater than 0 if errors occur.   This
>   is deliberately
>          a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you
>   should not rely on the correctness of
>   the  results  of
>          find.

Depending on what you want to achieve you could try to let find `-print` the filename and test against it's output:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYVAR=`find . -name "something" -print`
if [ -z "$MYVAR" ]; then
    echo "Notfound"
else
   echo $MYVAR
fi
```

Comment: It's certainly [possible](https://serverfault.com/a/829314/180589), although not as robust as one might want.

Comment: The manual page is poorly organized; what Ruslan said is documentated under the `exec`/`execdir` option (used with `+`): `If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit status.`

Answer (score 3):

I feel that this is the most concise and direct method:

```
test `find /tmp/ -name something -print -quit 2>/dev/null`
```

Comment: In this case, if find had an error it would print the result to /dev/null, return a non-zero exit, and then have that fixed to 0 by the test command.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. Please describe your example. If there is an error and find exits, then the string will be empty and test will return non-zero.

Comment: I'm not sure what your example might be, but I accidentally omitted `-print -quit`, which might address your concern.

Comment: Perhaps the other person who downvoted (presumably for the same reason) can provide a contrary example?

Comment: The basic problem comes from redirecting stderr to /dev/null. If you're running this as a scripted job, you'd never be aware of any errors even if the script did find a file. You wouldn't be aware that it was perhaps missing files it couldn't access due to permissions issues such as directories that don't have read permissions set. Remove that and let the parent script discard stderr if it is appropriate.

Comment: Okay, you just don't like my style. For my use cases, any errors that find might report are either noise or so serious that they'll show up elsewhere. In any case, this method correctly answers the ultimate question: "Is there an accessible file in the path by the given name." An error will return a correct answer of "No". If I want to find out why not, I can add more complex code that answers questions not originally posed here.

Comment: Should it not be `test -n`? i.e. if the output of `find` is not empty, return 0 else return 1...?

Comment: One small problem is where the path beneath /tmp has a space in it; then `test` fails because it's a unary operator.  This can easily be fixed, though, by surrounding the backtick expression with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little script I called `test.py`. It improves upon other methods posted in that it will return an error code if one is set, and it additionally set one if find didn't list any files:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

p = Popen(['find'] + sys.argv)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode:
    sys.exit(p.returncode)
if not out:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Here's the command-line output:

```
$ python test.py . -maxdepth 1 -name notthere
$ echo $?
1
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name notthere
$ echo $?
0
$ find . -failedarg
find: unknown predicate `-failedarg'
$ echo $?
1
```

Then, for a result where find had errors but found files:

```
$ ls -lh
$ d---------  2 jeff users   6 Feb  6 11:49 noentry
$ find .
.
./noentry
find: `./noentry': Permission denied
$ echo $?
1
$ find . | egrep '.*'
.
./noentry
find: `./noentry': Permission denied
$ echo $?
0
python ../test.py 
../test.py
$ echo $?
1
```

Then, if you want the list of files you can make use of `-print 0` passed to `find` and split the out variable on nulls, or you can just add a print statement for it.

Answer (score -5):

It is not only `find` that returns the exit status codes as zero when it successful. In unix what ever the command you execute, if its succeeds then it returns the exit status as zero.